# OLEDB DBase VI :Syntax error in field definition

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf, dbase

I am trying to create a DBF table when i get this error "Syntax error in field definition." , however there is nothing wrong with syntax , and when I change a certain column name from level to levels it debug just fine! anybody have an idea ? 
here is the code:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= D://Temp;Extended Properties=dBase IV";

//MessageBox.Show(connectionString);

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();

/* --------------------------  Filling The DBF Files ------------------------*/
 using (OleDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
 {
   cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE clients(
               nbrclient   int             ,    
               level      varchar(1)      , 
               type        varchar(10)     ,
               name        varchar(80)     ,    
               name2       varchar(80)     ,    
               fname       varchar(50)     ,    
               vip         varchar(40)     ,
               langue     varchar(3)      , 
               salutations varchar(30)     ,
               gender      varchar(30)     ,
               title       varchar(30)    
                                        ) ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Level is probably a reserved word.  This worked when I tried it:

```
[level]      varchar(1),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace VARCHAR type to CHARACTER.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , @LarsTech you're absolutly right ,  The good News is I have find a work around, Use (`) before and after the reserved word so instead of level`Level`passed with no problem at all  Be careful not to confuse (') with (`).
thank you all for your good work and advise